# Help with boot-repair

Tags: boot

All of a sudden I can't boot into Ubuntu 22.04. What can I do to get up and running again?

Here is the boot-repair summary:

```
boot-repair-4ppa203                                              [20221219_1620]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

sdg: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdg and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdg: /dev/sdg already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Trinity [Radeon HD 7660D] EFI VGA from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 7.11(4.6) from AMI
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled - This system doesn't support Secure Boot.
BootCurrent: 000B
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0009,000A,0003,0001,0002,000B,0000,0004,0006,0005,0007,0008
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,MBR,0xc18980b2,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* USB Floppy/CD VenMedia(b6fef66f-1495-4584-a836-3492d1984a8d,0500000001)AMBO
Boot0002* USB Hard Drive    VenMedia(b6fef66f-1495-4584-a836-3492d1984a8d,0200000001)AMBO
Boot0003  ubuntu    HD(1,MBR,0x87c70b8b,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0004* ATAPI CD-ROM Drive    VenMedia(b6fef66f-1495-4584-a836-3492d1984a8d,0300000001)AMBO
Boot0005* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........o.h.p. . . . . . .D.V.D.-.R.A.M. .S.W.8.1.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.2.1.6.1.P.T.0.0.2.5.4.6.S.T.1.H. .H. . ......AMBO
Boot0006* USB Floppy/CD VenMedia(b6fef66f-1495-4584-a836-3492d1984a8d,0500000000)AMBO
Boot0007* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........q.H.P. .P.h.o.t.o.s.m.a.r.t. .5.5.2.0. .1...0.0....................A.......................D..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.H.P. .P.h.o.t.o.s.m.a.r.t. .5.5.2.0. .1...0.0......AMBOAMNO........o.P.N.Y. .C.S.9.0.0. .1.2.0.G.B. .S.S.D....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.N.P.2.Y.1.1.2.4.0.1.0.4.0.6.0.1.D.0.D.9......AMBOAMNO........y.G.e.n.e.r.a.l. .U.S.B. .F.l.a.s.h. .D.i.s.k. .1.1.0.0....................A.......................L..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.G.e.n.e.r.a.l. .U.S.B. .F.l.a.s.h. .D.i.s.k. .1.1.0.0......AMBO
Boot0008* Atheros Boot Agent    BBS(Network,,0x0)AMBO
Boot0009  ubuntu    HD(1,MBR,0xf217301a,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot000A  ubuntu    HD(1,MBR,0xf8a0a474,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot000B* UEFI: General USB Flash Disk 1100 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x10,0x1)/USB(4,0)/HD(2,GPT,9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a12-46dc207b42ee,0x71e8a0,0x2130)AMBO


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________


Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________


Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________


fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 111.79 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk sdg: 14.92 GiB, 16025387008 bytes, 31299584 sectors
Disk identifier: 9240A165-D190-4AB6-8A10-46DC207B42EE
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdg1       64  7465119  7465056  3.6G Microsoft basic data
sdg2  7465120  7473615     8496  4.1M EFI System
sdg3  7473616  7474215      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdg4  7475200 31299520 23824321 11.4G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:120GB:scsi:512:512:unknown:ATA PNY CS900 120GB:;
sdg:16.0GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:General USB Flash Disk:;
1:32.8kB:3822MB:3822MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:3822MB:3826MB:4350kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:3826MB:3827MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:3827MB:16.0GB:12.2GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                
sdb                                                                                                                
sdc                                                                                                                
sdd                                                                                                                
sde                                                                                                                
sdg    iso9660  2022-08-10-16-21-45-00                                                    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sdg1 iso9660  2022-08-10-16-21-45-00               9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a11-46dc207b42ee Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdg2 vfat     8D6C-A9F8                            9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a12-46dc207b42ee ESP                      Appended2
├─sdg3                                               9240a165-d190-4ab6-8a13-46dc207b42ee                          Gap1
└─sdg4 ext4     26f315e2-7097-4e97-a724-56aa610b4894 778c3857-277a-5b4c-95fe-7632e1ed4d9b writable                 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                              Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-12-19.2/crash] 10.5G   0% /var/crash
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-12-19.2/log]   10.5G   0% /var/log
/dev/sdg1                                                         0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________




Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.
```

Comment: You are not even showing partitions on sda, just a blank sda drive? Your UEFI shows multiple Ubuntu UEFI boot entries using different GUID/partUUIDs, but none shown. They must be on sda. Does anything show partitions on sda? Try parted rescue or testdisk. If not shown check cables, may be loose or damaged, but otherwise drive may have failed.

Comment: sudo fsck /dev/sdg4 from a live cd in terminal , I just logged in to can see the report that you sent above. so use fsck /dev/sdg4

Comment: $ sudo fsck /dev/sdg4
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/sdg4 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

Comment: $ sudo fdisk -l    Disk /dev/sda: 111.79 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors    Disk model: PNY CS900 120GB  Disk /dev/sdg: 14.92 GiB, 16025387008 bytes, 31299584 sectors Disk model: USB Flash Disk

Comment: Told you command can't fix mounted partition, so the disk you need to fix must be slave on a master running device as a Ubuntu live CD, but I can see that oldfred found your wright problem, you need to recover a partition , or reinstall the Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot from Ubuntu live CD and choose try without install.
2. Open terminal ctrl + alt + T from keyboard or click windows in
   keyboard then type terminal in search box
3. In Terminal type `fsck /dev/sda2` then enter , if it needed root
   add sudo to be `sudo fsck /dev/sda2`

**Note: sda2 where your system running , to know if it's the same or different number open disk program from the programs menue where you find terminal by search it, then choose the hard disk and click on the file system partition you will find after size , Devise /dev/sdX0 where x it's letter and 0 the number write what you will find instead a2 , x0 ...

Comment: Try editing your answer to break it up for readability and add some whitespace. On my first read of it, I couldn't tell what you actually wanted the person to do. There are editing features to add numbered bullet points. I edited this one for you to show you what I mean.

Comment: If the system not running at all this command should fix it as I tried then you will not need to use Boot repair CD , If the problem only with Boot repair he need to active EFI Boot option that the new versions of Boot repair only support, if the device haven't EFI the current Boot repair option will not work to fix system.  just on Live CD on running system will say can't umount partition.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an update Bassem.  Here is what I tried
I opened GParted.  It shows 2 partitions.

/dev/sda (111.79 GiB)   Partition: unallocated! File System Unallocated
/dev/sdg (14.92 GiB)    Partition: /dev/sdg File System: iso9660 Ubuntu 22.04 LTS amd64

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
fsck.ext2: No such file or directory while trying to open /dev/sda2
Possibly non-existent device?
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid
ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an
ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate
superblock:
e2fsck -b 8193 
or
e2fsck -b 32768

Comment: You can only run fsck on a formatted partition not on a drive. But you are not showing any partitions on sda. And additional info should be in original question, not in an answer. You need to see if you can recovery partitions? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: I ran TestDisk on sda. It could not find a boot partition. When I installed Ubuntu 22.04 I used LUKS 2. Could this boot problem be due to LUKS? Is it possible that the LUKS partition has been overwritten by $sudo apt upgrade?

Comment: An apt command would not erase the drive. Was this LUKs with full drive encryption. If so, the rule is if it takes more than an hour to repair, better to just do a total new install & restore from your backups. With encryption, you really must have good backups. But that drive shows nothing & testdisk does not find the partition the LUKs volumes would be in, may indicate a drive issue.

Answer (score 0):

Richard follow these pictures  I found in your report that your partition is sdg4

1- open disk

2- choose the system partition and copy it's Device information in front of device under size

3- in terminal type `fsck` then press space and past the information you copied or write it then press enter I think at you `fsck /dev/sdg4`
you maybe need to add sudo root so will type`sudo fsck` then past device information about the system partition.
At you I think it will be `sudo fsck /dev/sdg4`

Note: you mast be on a live CD ""try Ubuntu without install"" to work
on running installed system it will say can't umount it, also only system partition can be fix by FSCK.

you can also put the hard as a slave on a running master hard with Ubuntu then choose the letter and number in this case maybe will give sdb2 instead sdb1 if no more devices.

[image: Open disk program]

[image: Dev info]

Comment: It looks like sdg is flash drive and issue is with sda which is not showing any partitions to try to fsck.

Comment: That's right oldfred.  Its a bootable flash drive.